# How to save checklist values into MySQL & be able to re-populate the checkboxes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I cannot figure out how to save checked checkbox form input into MySQL and be able to retrieve them and re-populate the inputs.

I haven't even created a table yet because I cannot mentalize how go by doing it.

I have an html table with multiple rows(tr) and inside it all the tables have these checkboxes and I am wanting to save each of the selected boxes to MySQL and 
be able to retrieve the selected ones and re-populate it, but as I said I cannot figure out how to do it.

The only way I can think of is, submit the selected with a foreach and save all the selected ones, in each row with their specific table row iD but I don't understand how I would retrieve it if they are selected.

I've got the following but no idea how it would be retrievable. Also, the checkboxes can increase at any time(the options) so I cannot create a specific table for them as there are currently 4 checkboxes, but tomorrow it can be 20 checkboxes to choose from.

```
$checkboxData = $_POST['cbO'];
$tableiD      = '1';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    for( $i=0; $i < sizeof($checkboxData); $i++ )
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(rows) VALUES (:checkboxInfo) WHERE table_id = :tableiD");
        $sth->execute(array(
               ':checkboxInfo' => $checkboxData[$i],
               ':tableiD' => $tableiD)
        );
    }
}

<form method="post" action="">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cbO[]" value="349169846048613138">CheckBox1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cbO[]" value="349169846048613136">CheckBox2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cbO[]" value="349169846048613140">CheckBox3</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cbO[]" value="349169846048613141">CheckBox4</li>

    <input type="submit" name"submit" value"Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of `$1` change it to `$i` since your looping `$checkboxData`'s values which naturally sets the first value to `[0]` and so on

Comment: your insert is wrong syntax (`WHERE` is not valid in `INSERT`,   try something like -> `INSERT INTO table(rows,table_id) VALUES (:checkboxInfo,:tableiD)`

Comment: and to add on to @Sean's point, just make the table's `id` `AUTO INCREMENT`

Comment: For setting the value, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/in_array)/[`in_array()`](http://php.net/isset) -> `if(isset($_POST['cbO']) && in_array(349169846048613138,$_POST['cbO'])) echo "checked='checked'"`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the variable amount of items, get the items from the database and make a loop with them:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<ul>
<?php if (!empty($items)) foreach ($itens as $i => $value) { ?>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cbO[<?= $i ?>]" value="<?= $value ?>"> 
        CheckBox<?= ($i + 1) ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a `print_r($_POST)` on the value class you expect to receive, then the value will be what you expect it to be always.